# Select a specific record in a group of records for all groups of records in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a table that contains many different records for products specifications, the products may appear more than once in the table as they have different colors. In order to display the products in a screen I need to select a list of them with the color YELLOW, but if YELLOW is not present I need color BLUE, or else I don't want this product.

Simplified Products example:

```
+----+--------+
| ID | NAME   |
+----+--------+
|  1 | Prod A |
|  2 | Prod B |
|  3 | Prod C |
|  4 | Prod D |
+----+--------+
```

Simplied Spec table:

```
+----+------------+--------+
| ID | ID_PRODUCT | COLOR  |
+----+------------+--------+
|  1 |          1 | BLUE   |
|  2 |          1 | YELLOW |
|  3 |          2 | RED    |
|  4 |          2 | PINK   |
|  5 |          3 | BLUE   |
|  6 |          3 | GRAY   |
|  7 |          4 | YELLOW |
+----+------------+--------+
```

Expected results:

```
+----+------------+--------+
| ID | ID_PRODUCT | COLOR  |
+----+------------+--------+
|  2 |          1 | YELLOW |
|  5 |          3 | BLUE   |
|  7 |          4 | YELLOW |
+----+------------+--------+
```

Raw SQL for this example:

```
CREATE TABLE `colors` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `ID_PRODUCT` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `COLOR` varchar(16) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE `products` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `NAME` varchar(16) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `colors` VALUES (1,1,'BLUE'),(2,1,'YELLOW'),(3,2,'RED'),(4,2,'PINK'),(5,3,'BLUE'),(6,3,'GRAY'),(7,4,'YELLOW');

INSERT INTO `products` VALUES (1,'Prod A'),(2,'Prod B'),(3,'Prod C'),(4,'Prod D');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one option using `conditional aggregation`:

```
select id_product, 
       max(case when color = 'YELLOW' then id
                when color = 'BLUE' then id
           end),
       max(case when color = 'YELLOW' then color
                when color = 'BLUE' then color
           end) 
from colors
where color in ('YELLOW','BLUE')
group by id_product
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ac69e1/2)

Comment: My poor English comprehension made me not understand correctly your concern for the answer I accepted. Indeed in Darshan Mehta's answer the ID will not always be the correct one. Your answer is more complex but correct.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one method:

```
select c.*
from colors c
where c.color = 'YELLOW'
union all
select c.*
from colors c
where c.color = 'BLUE' and
      not exists (select 1
                  from colors c2
                  where c2.id_product = c.id_product and c2.color = 'YELLOW'
                 );
```

Comment: Thanks for this too, but it seems too complex due to the union and sub-select.

Comment: @AndréDias . . . With the right indexes, this is probably the fastest way to get the results you want.

Comment: Hi, please tell me what indexes (in an amateur way if possible) I need to add so I can compare both solutions. I have over 80000 records to play with.

Answer (score 0):

If it's always going to be blue and yellow comparison then I'd just use `max()` function, e.g.

```
select id, id_product, max(color) from colors
where color in ('BLUE','YELLOW')
group by id_product;
```

Comment: While this will return the correct color, it will return an arbitrary value for the `id` field.  `mysql` allows this behavior, most other databases do not...

Comment: Since in this subject mysql is the only database that matters I accepted this as a solution as it is the simplest from all options.

Comment: I understand now what you mean by "arbitrary value for the id", this solution does not work as expected.